# Can't view properties of an hba in vSphere 5.5

Tags: storage-area-network, vmware-vsphere, fiber, hba

Why can't I view the properites of this HBA in vSphere?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal for a hardware storage adapter in my experience.

What properties are you expecting to see?

Comment: Never used vSphere before and havent plugged in the HBA yet. I thought maybe there was a problem with it.